# Best way to get article from a database along with connected tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get articles and all tag names which they're connected to from a MySQL database. My SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE connections (
    art_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

Should I perform several queries or make single big one? How can I achive that? I tried to play with JOIN, but it seems it cannot be done that way.

PS. I've been searching, but there is no EXACT question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.id, group_concat(t.name) as tags
from articles a
left join connections c on c.art_id = a.id
left join tag t on t.id = c.tag_id
group by a.id
```

This query returns 1 row per article, and [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will return the names of all connected tags as a [comma delimited list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (or null if there are no connected tags).

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a great start - but there are a few things that can be optimized here.

Let's also assume your Article table has an ID and a Title field (just to add some spice to this query).

To simply answer your questions:

```
Select a.ID "ID", a."Title" "Title", t.Name "Tag_Name"
From connections c
     Left Join article a 
     on a.id = c.art_id
     Left Join tags t 
     on t.id = c.tag_id
-- If you want to filter on a certain article ID 
WHERE a.id = @SomeArticleParam
```

I would really advise a couple things to optimize these tables:

1. Since connections directly links articles and tags, I would add foreign key references to the connections table.  Here is a good link: [foreign key link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).
2. Index your connections table - this will allow faster queries when referencing specific tags or articles.  A Unique index will help prevent adding duplicate article/tag pairs in the connections table.  Here is a good link to get you started: [index link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select a.(*),t.name from articles a
  inner join connection c on a.id=c.art_id
  inner join tags t on c.tag_id=t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT articles.*,tags.* FROM articles , tags,connections 
 where tags.id=connections.tag_id  and articles.id=connections.art_id
```